# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException with com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.UserAttributeParcel

Tags: android, firebase

Whenever I run my app I get this in the logs:

```
java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.UserAttributeParcel>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/safeparcel/AbstractSafeParcelable;
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName!(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:400)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String) (Class.java:326)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Iterable) ((null):-1)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions, java.lang.String) ((null):-1)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions) ((null):-1)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at boolean com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate() ((null):-1)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo, boolean) (ContentProvider.java:1793)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo) (ContentProvider.java:1762)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo) ((null):-1)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(android.content.Context, android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo, boolean, boolean, boolean) (ActivityThread.java:6205)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(android.content.Context, java.util.List) (ActivityThread.java:5768)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:5707)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1577)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:173)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6523)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:938)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:828)
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.medishare.zeeromed-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.medishare.zeeromed-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.medishare.zeeromed-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.medishare.zeeromed-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.medishare.zeeromed-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.medishare.zeeromed-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.medishare.zeeromed-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.medishare.zeeromed-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.medishare.zeeromed-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.medishare.zeeromed-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.medishare.zeeromed-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.medishare.zeeromed-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"]
06-22 16:39:48.124 6169-6169/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName!(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:400)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String) (Class.java:326)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Iterable) ((null):-1)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions, java.lang.String) ((null):-1)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions) ((null):-1)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(android.content.Context) ((null):-1)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at boolean com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate() ((null):-1)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo, boolean) (ContentProvider.java:1793)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo) (ContentProvider.java:1762)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(android.content.Context, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo) ((null):-1)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(android.content.Context, android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder, android.content.pm.ProviderInfo, boolean, boolean, boolean) (ActivityThread.java:6205)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(android.content.Context, java.util.List) (ActivityThread.java:5768)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:5707)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$AppBindData) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1577)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:173)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6523)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:938)
06-22 16:39:48.125 6169-6169/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:828)
```

After searching online I guessed it was caused by an incopatibility inside my build.gradle. After resolving it I still get those lines in the log. The interesting thing is that everything works as expected inside the app even if this error is thrown every time. My other guess is that this was caused by the fact that I converted all the cloud functions to Firebase some time ago and did some mistakes. Thank you for your help.

My app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        renderscriptTargetApi 25
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled false
        applicationId "com.medishare.zeeromed"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile project(path: ':subProject:android-networking')

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar:horizontalcalendar:1.1.5'
    compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:viewanimator:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    //compile 'com.github.shalskar:PeekAndPop:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bassaer:chatmessageview:1.3.3'
    compile 'com.github.simbiose:Encryption:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.irozon.sneaker:sneaker:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.2'
    compile 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.0.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.0'
}

// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Post your app module build.gradle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` should be after the dependencies block, where you now have it commented:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // <= REMOVE THIS
    ...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // <= BELONGS HERE
```